# Separate paddings top/bottom/left/right work, one padding doesn't. Why?

Tags: html, css, sass, padding

I want to customize a button in scss file connected to html.

It is a flex layout.

The size of the element itself is 83.333×16px.

box-sizing is

> box-sizing: border-box;

When I enter

> padding-top: 1rem;
>
> padding-bottom: 1rem;
>
> padding-left: 1.875rem;
>
> padding-right: 1.875rem;

it works.

When I type

> padding: 1rem 1.875rem;

it doesn't work.

Should I enable anything? How come such a simple syntax doesn't work?
I tried to search it on Google, but never found anything relevant.

Comment: More infos is needed to demonstrate your issue. What is the size of that element, is box-sizing involved, is it a float,block,flex,grid layout ? etc...

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I've added some. Does it help?

Comment: you have a snippet button `[<>]` , click it and add your HTML and CSS to show that your padding is not working (you can use also fake text and fake image if needed) fake text : https://www.webfx.com/web-design/html-ipsum/  (among others) fake image : https://picsum.photos/images (among others)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
padding: 1rem 1.875rem 1rem 1.875rem;
```

If I remember correctly, you read the padding values clockwise, so: top, right, bottom, left.

Comment: this is what `padding: 1rem 1.875rem;`  does too :)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus the funny thing is the latter worked, and my padding didn't.

Comment: @P.Vowk a typo maybe ? both do the same ;) (creating a snippet in the question might have help you discover what you did wrong ;) )

Comment: @G-Cyrillus might have been a typo, even though I checked it thrice, I suppose. Both work now... Should I delete my question?